# LinkedIn Not Displaying Open Graph Description

Tags: linkedin-api, meta-tags, share-open-graph

I have properly configured all the HTML Open Graph meta tags for sharing my webpage on LinkedIn, but the `og:description` of my page is not being displayed when shared. Here is the link to [my webpage](https://www.cantinefatteadarte.it/servizi/capanne-vinicole). Why is LinkedIn not retrieving the description?